# Use insertion sort to sort vowels at the beginning of string

Tags: java, insertion-sort

Is it possible to use insertion sort algorithm to sort the vowels at the beginning of a string?

I tried a lot but I don't get it , has somebody a hint how it could be implemented or should I use an other sort algorithm?

```java
    static char[] text = "thisIsAString".toCharArray();

    static void instertionSort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            char h = text[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            while ((j >= 0) && Character.toLowerCase(text[j]) > Character.toLowerCase(h)) {

                    text[j+1] = text[j];
                    j = j - 1;

            }

            text[j+1] = h;
        }
    }
```

Example: "thisIsAString" -> "AiiIghnrssStt"

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and desired output?

Comment: u can now read the example

Comment: Should it be `AiIighnrssStt`?

Comment: no lower case before upper case

Comment: you may also want to add where you define/declare the `string` variable (I assume it is a field somewhere). Note: I would not give it that name, as `String` is also a type in Java.

Comment: yeah it is a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use insertion sort for this (just like every other sort-algorithm, they are all equal. Only the time they take for sorting the field is different, but the result is always the same).

The problem in your algorithm is that you don't check whether the compared characters are vowels or upper/lower case.

This code should work:

```
public class StringSorter {

    private static final String vowels = "aeiou";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] string = "thisIsAString".toCharArray();
        char[] test2 = "thisIsAStringaAabBs".toCharArray();

        System.out.println("unsorted: " + new String(string));
        insertionSort(string);
        System.out.println("sorted:   " + new String(string));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("unsorted: " + new String(test2));
        insertionSort(test2);
        System.out.println("sorted:   " + new String(test2));
    }

    public static void insertionSort(char[] string) {
        for (int i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
            char h = string[i];
            int j = i;

            while ((j > 0) && isBefore(string[j - 1], h)) {

                string[j] = string[j - 1];
                j = j - 1;

            }

            string[j] = h;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBefore(char a, char b) {
        String lowA = Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(a));
        String lowB = Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(b));

        if (vowels.contains(lowA)) {
            if (vowels.contains(lowB)) {
                //both are vowels
                return chooseLowerCaseFirst(a, b);
            }
            else {
                //only a is a vowel
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (vowels.contains(lowB)) {
            //only b is a vowel
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //none is a vowel
            return chooseLowerCaseFirst(a, b);
        }
    }

    private static boolean chooseLowerCaseFirst(char a, char b) {
        String lowA = Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(a));
        String lowB = Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(b));

        if (lowA.equals(lowB)) {
            //both are the same character

            if (Character.isLowerCase(a)) {
                if (Character.isLowerCase(b)) {
                    //both are lower case
                    return Character.toLowerCase(a) > Character.toLowerCase(b);
                }
                else {
                    //only a is lower case
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(b)) {
                //only b is lower case
                return true;
            }
            else {
                //both are upper case
                return Character.toLowerCase(a) > Character.toLowerCase(b);
            }
        }
        else {
            //different characters
            return Character.toLowerCase(a) > Character.toLowerCase(b);
        }
    }
}
```

The output that is generated is:

```
unsorted: thisIsAString
sorted:   AiiIghnrssStt

unsorted: thisIsAStringaAabBs
sorted:   aaAAiiIbBghnrsssStt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering other methods too, from Java 8 you can do it by mixing [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    private static List<Character> order = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z'));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "thisIsAString";
        List<Character> cl = example.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Character> ls = cl.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(order::indexOf)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character c : ls) result.append(c);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```